# file handling in cpp not writing string properly

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, file-handling

C++ not writing string to text file in proper format. [This is the code](https://onlinegdb.com/ot3zpnfth)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

class student
{  
    string name;
    int roll;
    float per;

  public:
    void put()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Roll no.: " << roll << endl;
        cout << "Percentage: " << per << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    void get()
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter your roll no.: ";
        cin >> roll;
        cout << "Enter your percentage: ";
        cin >> per;
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student s;
    fstream f;

    int ch;
    while(1)
        {
         cout<<"\n-------------------MENU-------------------\n";
         cout<<"1.Add Record\n";
         cout<<"2.Search\n";
         cout<<"3.Delete\n";
         cout<<"4.Modify\n";
         cout<<"5.Display File\n";
         cout<<"6.QUIT\n";

        cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin>>ch;
    
            switch(ch)
            {
             case 1:
                    f.open("student.txt", ios::app);
                    s.get();
                    f.write((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
                    f.close();
                    break;
                        
             case 5:
                    f.open("student.txt", ios::in);
                    while (f.eof() != 0)
                    {
                        f.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
                        s.put();
                    }
                    f.close();
                    break;
    
             case 6: cout << "Quiting\n";
                    return -1;
    
            default: cout << "Invalid input";
            }
        }   

    return 0;
}
```

I want to write name, percentage & roll no. of student to the text file but it's writing it improperly (in binary I guess). How can I fix it? [This is how the text file looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgIMx.png)

Comment: `f.write((char*)&s, sizeof(s));` you can not do this for class or struct that contains a non POD type.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code shown doesn't need any of the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.